# Show that $S$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

> Suppose $T$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on a set $Y$ and $X \in T$. Let $S = \{E \in T: E \subset X\}$.

> (a) Show that $S = \{F \cap X: F \in T\}.$

> (b) Show that $S$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$.

(a) By definition of $S$, a subset $F$ is in $T$ if $F \subset X$. If $F \subset X$, we can write $F \subset X = F \cap X$. The equality holds because if we take $x \in F\subset X$, then $x \in F \cap X$ and taking $x \in F \cap X$, then $x \in F$.

(b) Since $T$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, $\emptyset \in T$. Thus $\exists E \in T$ such that $E = \emptyset$. Further, if $E = \emptyset$, then $E \cap X = \emptyset$ so $ \emptyset \in S$. Since $X \in T$, any $E \subset X$ is also in $T$ so $X/E \in T$ by the fact that $T$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Then note that $X/E \subset X$ so $X/E$ is in $S$. Finally, let $F_1 \cap X, F_2 \cap X, \dots$ be a countable sequence of elements of $S$. The union $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}(F_k \cap X) \iff F_1 \cup F_2 \cup \dots \cap X$, which is contained in $S$. Thus $S$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$.

Just wondering if my proof is right on showing that $S$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, particularly trying to show that $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} \in S.$, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) Looks very sloppy to me. You need to show that $S \subseteq \{F \cap X: F \in T\}$ and $S \supseteq \{F \cap X: F \in T\}$.

Your proof argues the first inclusion, you still need to show the second. To do this, pick $F \in T$ set $G=F \cap X$ and argue that $G \in S$.

(b) You are overkilling $\emptyset \in S$. Indeed since $\emptyset \in T$ and $\emptyset \subseteq X$ by the definition of $S$ you get $\emptyset \in S$.

The closure under complement looks good.

For countable union, you are overkilling it by trying to use (a).

Note that if $E_1,E_2,..., E_n,... \in S$ then you know that for all $n$ you have $E_n \in T$ and $E_n \subseteq X$. To prove that $\cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n \in S$ you need to show that  $\cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n \in T$ and $\cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n \subseteq X$, both of which are trivial.